# How do I get a hidden layer to remain visible and clickable over a linked object?

Tags: html, css

This is the site in question: http://www.seven-lakes-exposure.com/

The problem I'm having is the drop down submenu appears over the slideshow, but you can't click on "Landscapes" without it disappearing.

This only occurs when the submenu is overlapping the slideshow. Otherwise, the submenu works fine.

Using `pointer-events: none` on the slideshow enables you to click on the submenu without it disappearing, but obviously it disables the slideshow events, which I don't want.

How do I keep a clickable event visible over another clickable event?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: My guess is that there is a mousemove effect present on the whole body. When it detects the move over the gallery it takes focus and dismisses the menu.

Comment: Any idea how to go about fixing it?

Comment: No, because you are using a control I don't know and the control's JS-files are obfuscated.